# Laravel 5.6 Swift_TransportException Expected response code 250 but got code , with message PLAIN250 Reset OK

Tags: php, smtp, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to send email using Laravel 5.6 but I got this error

```
Swift_TransportException Expected response code 250 but got code , with message PLAIN250 Reset OK
```

This is my configuration:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=4403.smtp.antispamcloud.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=username@domain.tld
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Any ideas? Thx

Comment: Maybe [this issue](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/788) might be of use

Answer (score 0):

Check your gmail account: in settings, enable access for less secure apps and it will work.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but how does OPs gmail account relate to all this? gmail is mentioned nowhere in OPs post.

Comment: I'm not using gmail.